# Expression of $2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{r_{0}}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{r_{0}-r_{s}}{r_{0}^{3}}-u^{2}\left(1-u r_{s}\right)}}$ in terms of elliptic integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals, general-relativity

In [Gravitation by Misner et al. 1973](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1973grav.book.....M) the authors state that (calculus related to the Schwarzschild metric page 678) :

$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{r_{0}}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{r_{0}-r_{s}}{r_{0}^{3}}-u^{2}\left(1-u r_{s}\right)}}= 4\sqrt{\frac{r_{0}}{q}}\left(F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, k\right)-F\left(\sigma_{0}, k\right)\right)-\pi$$
with :
$$
\begin{cases}
F\left(\sigma, k\right) &= \int_{0}^{\sigma}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}}\\
q &= \sqrt{r_{0}^{2}+2r_{0}r_{s}-3r_{s}^{2}} \\
k &= \sqrt{\frac{q-r_{0}+3r_{s}}{2q}}\\
\sigma_{0} &= \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{q-r_{0}+r_{s}}{q-r_{0}+3r_{s}}}\right)\\
\end{cases}$$
Neither Maple nor Mathematica seem to be able to find this form.

How to demonstrate it ?

Comment: I assume this is related to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/779403/1543)?

Comment: Anyhow, if I am not mistaken, the original demonstration via elliptic integrals was given by [Charles Darwin](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/263/1312/39.abstract) (no, a different, slightly less famous one). I don't have access to the article at the moment, however.